# Odd Complex analysis Identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was given a brain teaser by my friend, and I am having trouble solving this identity. I tried writing out the cos(z) into its components and I tried using the fact that $\left|e^z\right|\le e^{\left|z\right|}$ to no avail.

$Prove\:\:that\:\left|cos\left(z\right)\right|\le e^{\left|z\right|}\:for\:z\:\in \mathbb{C},\:z=\:x+\:iy\:\&\:x,y\:\in \mathbb{R}$

Any tips to prove this?

Comment: $\cos z=\frac {e^{iz}+e^{-iz}} 2$.

Comment: I am aware. I used this and didn't get anywhere

Comment: Do you know that $|z_1+z_2| \leq |z_1|+|z_2|$ and $|\pm iz|=|z|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that $\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ and $|e^z| \leq e^{|z|}$. Using this and the triangle inequality, we have

$$|\cos(z)| = \big| \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} \big| \leq \frac{1}{2} (|e^{iz}|+|e^{-iz}|) \leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{|iz|} + e^{|-iz|}) = e^{|z|}$$